# highChart pdf download

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

My pdf export does a complete export of the page, imagine if some legends and some chart elements are to disabled, and then I click on export, I still end up getting the pdf with all legends displayed, hwo do I overcome this ? 
I searched , somehow there was no legend ID available, 
the firebug console on Firefox shows me the highchart.js file , which I can barely read !
has someone done this, or can some one give me a direction.

Comment: Are you using the built in exporting methods of highcharts?  I just tried enabling/disabling a legend and my pdfs came out correctly.

Comment: Hey Mark, No I am using a tool evohtmltopdf tool,

Comment: Hey Mark, No I am using a tool evohtmltopdf tool,
which enables me to export the webpage as a pdf, but as u see the problem that I have is to extract the legend clicks somehow so I can then when I click on the pdf download button it should show me only the legends that are displayed , but I end up with the pdf file still showing me to all the legends, even though I had disabled some legends ! is there a legendClick activity, as I see there is a legendIndex that I can assign but nothing more!
and hints around this ??

Comment: So, if the built in export works, why not use that?

Comment: Yeah I stick  to this at the moment, had problems with the legend clicks not reflecting in the downloads but when I upgaded my highchart version to the latest it worked perfect, thanks for your time Mark !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem and when I used v2.2.5 for highchart.js and exporting.js it got resolved! Thanks for this discussion.